# EntityDrupalWrapper->value() causes infinite recursion on user login?

Tags: 7, entities

I have a few instances on my site where I perform actions on User Login.

I create an EntityMetadataWrapper like so:

```
global $user;
$uw = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $user);
```

And then I go to retrieve values like this:

```
$special_value = $uw->field_special_value->value()
```

For some reason, this particular line will cause an infinite recursion and crash my site.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? I am calling one of these from a Rules event and another one from `hook_user_login`, but it seems like no matter what, I get this recursive error.

This ONLY seems to happen in `hook_user_login`, all of my other `value()` calls to Entity Metadata Wrappers seem to work fine.

Note; these are both Entity References -- one references a Taxonomy Term and the other references a custom Entity.

Comment: Also, if I refresh the page and re-submit the form (via prompt from the browser), everything acts exactly as it should.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure the user is logged in and you have a full `$user` object available in your rule?

Maybe you have to call `$user = user_load($uid, TRUE);` explicity for this 1 case?

Comment: I have step-debugged this problem before, and I am 99% sure that I saw the $user object fully loaded from the global. I will double-check to ensure, and re-post here.

Comment: I have ensured that the user object is fully loaded. You can see a screenshot of my debugger window here: http://i.imgur.com/Z5exbeK.png.

Comment: I noticed that "field_bio" was also an empty array. If I try to load it via `$fb = $uw->field_bio->value();` it crashes, as well.